# Rewrite Rules WordPress Returning Category Page Instead of Individual post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, s3-rewrite-rules

I'm trying to change the permalink only to one specific category and it works good on the changing, but the content isn't right.

It's showing the categories page with a lot of posts instead of the proper content of that post.

Can someone help me with this?

The code:

```
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Educational" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/Educational/'. $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);


function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %postname%-%post_id% struture
    $new_rules['^Educational/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
    $new_rules['^Educational/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[2]';
    $new_rules['^Educational/?$'] = 'index.php?cat=61';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: I'm seeing three rewrite rules, however the second one overwrites the first. That said, is it possible to solve this with a hierarchical taxonomy instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not I guess... I need the rewrite rules to match the content